# trouble with media folder pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

pythonanywhere cant find files in me media folder
[image]

But I have this file!
[image]

roots in my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/dimabytes/my-first-blog/static'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/dimabytes/my-first-blog/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

me web page at pythonanywhere

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I automatically displayed the working directory in the folder with my name. It was necessary to finish the path of the project [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Hello, I cannot understand the difference between first and this pythonanywhere screen. What did you change? "It was necessary to finish the path of the project" do you mean you added "/" to the end of the static and media dir's on the pic?

Comment: Oh, I think yes. Share your email, and I will try to help you with it

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have your path configured incorrectly, either when you call for the media or your `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`, most likely the former. If you look at your pythonanywhere file storage and your error output, it's looking for the file in `media/static/<file_here>`. Your targeted file is in `/media/file/<file_here>`.

Comment: I am already tried this http://dpaste.com/3QVDF94 I dont understend what wrong :(